# Android: themes in xml

Tags: android, xml, themes

I have found this little line in a xml of a live wallpaper example

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings"
```

Now i have been looking around for a complete list of the themes which can be set above, but i just can't find it, can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android-sdk\platforms\android-8\data\res\values\themes.xml`

Comment: if you are on windows, `c:\program files\android` or wherever you installed the sdk

Comment: Thanks, but it's a bit messy and confusing, is there a list online somewhere just for the titles of the themes?